# Java Azure Function stuck "Executing"

Tags: java, azure-functions, visual-studio-code, azure-functions-runtime

I've been working on getting my local environment setup to develop an Azure Function written in java. It appears I've installed and configured all the necessary extensions but my function freezes once it's triggered. When I check open ports via `netstat` I can see that both ports 5005 and 7071 are open and I can see in the logs that the route /api/hello has been mapped.

I'm working behind a proxy but I've configured proxy settings for Maven and Windows.

Function.java

```
  @FunctionName("hello")
    public String hello(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { "get",
            "post" }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) String req, ExecutionContext context) {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

If I call an invalid endpoint I get the following message

```
Executed HTTP request: {
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM]   "requestId": "39732c95-6161-6251-asdf-8456654654",
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM]   "method": "GET",
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM]   "uri": "/api/notvalid",
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM]   "identities": [],
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM]   "status": 404,
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM]   "duration": 460
[12/2/2019 8:53:51 PM] }
```

When I enter the correct endpoint it gets "stuck"

```
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM] Executing HTTP request: {
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM]   "requestId": "7e266ae2-fae2-4022-bbeb-ce9cad0b12ef",
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM]   "method": "GET",
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM]   "uri": "/api/hello"
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM] }
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM] Request successfully matched the route with name 'hello' and template 'api/hello'
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM] Executing 'Functions.hello' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=654dddsd-bcdb-40e7-sdfd-3b59f1afd145)
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM] Sending invocation id:05d49684-bcdb-40e7-a557-3b59f1afd145
   [12/2/2019 10:07:07 PM] Posting invocation id:078d99a2-bcdb-40e7-a557-3b59f1afd145 on workerId:bd56d65b-3cfb-43ae-891e-d564d654s6d54s
```

Complete Output Logs

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1948 Commit hash: a6sd5f4ad56a+sdf654asd65f4d56f44ew6de5f4d6s)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12888.0
[12/2/2019 8:49:13 PM] Starting worker process:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java  -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:5005 -Xmx1g "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\java\azure-functions-java-worker.jar" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 64485 --workerId 2c6fa8bb-e3e1-4479-a97e-0afad93eb108 --requestId af882984-8364-42ff-8420-9716da75f8fa --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[12/2/2019 8:49:13 PM] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java process with Id=7436 started
[12/2/2019 8:49:13 PM] [INFO] {Application.main}: Azure Functions Java Worker  version [ 1.5.2-SNAPSHOT]
[12/2/2019 8:49:15 PM] [INFO] {MessageHandler.handle}: Message generated by "StartStream.Builder"
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: 'sdfgsdfgsdf-sdfg-sdfg-sdfg-sdfgsdfgsdfgd'
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] Reading host configuration file 
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] Host configuration file read:
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] {
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM]   "version": "2.0"
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] }
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] Reading functions metadata
[12/2/2019 8:49:17 PM] 1 functions found
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] Initializing Host. OperationId: 'e723b517-b610-41ac-9ab1-fd013e235a2f'.
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=e723b517-b610-41ac-9ab1-fd013e235a2f
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] LoggerFilterOptions
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "MinLevel": "None",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "Rules": [
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]     {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "ProviderName": null,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]     },
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]     {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "LogLevel": "None",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "Filter": null
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]     },
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]     {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]     }
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   ]
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] }
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "IsEnabled": true
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] }
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] SingletonOptions
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] }
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] HttpOptions
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] {
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] }
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] Starting JobHost
[12/2/2019 8:49:18 PM] Starting Host (HostId=c001809356-764127483, InstanceId=415c4ded-7728-4dd7-a2db-cbebdb13eaeb, Version=2.0.12888.0, ProcessId=5156, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Loading functions metadata
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] 1 functions loaded
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] [INFO] {DefaultClassLoaderProvider.addUrl}: Loading file URL: file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/function/target/azure-functions/function/function-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Found the following functions:
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Host.Functions.hello
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM]
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Initializing function HTTP routes
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Mapped function route 'api/hello' [get,post] to 'hello'
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM]
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Host initialized (586ms)
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Host started (598ms)
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Job host started
[12/2/2019 8:49:19 PM] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\user\Documentation
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Http Functions:

        hello: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/hello
```

Comment: I tried changing the trigger to see if that helped and it's still getting stuck on Posting Invocation...

Comment: What do you mean stuck? You trigger the function, however it doesn't return the result or it doesn't run?

Comment: was this resolved, how did you resolved this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return a http response instead of the string:

```
return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello").build();
```

Comment: `req` is an instance of String.